# Clojure - Memory usage parsing smallish CSV file

Tags: csv, memory, clojure, garbage-collection

I am trying to parse a 50MB CSV file. ~2500 rows, ~5500 columns, one column is strings (date as yyyy-mm-dd) and the rest is floats with lots of empty points. I need to be able to access all the data so would like to realize the full file, which should be possible at that size.

I've tried a few options from:

`(with-open [rdr (io/reader path)] (doall (csv/read-csv rdr))))`

to slightly more manual ways using `line-seq` and parsing the string into numbers manually.

My JVM usage on a single `slurp` goes up 100MB, 2x the file size. On parsing the data I go up 1-2GB depending on how it's done. If I open and parse the file several times into the same variable, memory usage keep going up and I end up with a memory error and the program fails. (I understand looking at the task manager isn't the best way to look at memory leaks, but the fact is the program fails so there is a leak somewhere)

What is the right way of opening the file? My final use case is I'll be getting a new file every day and I want a server application to open the file and crunch data every day without running out of memory and needing to restart the server.

Edit: for comparison reading that file with Python pandas will consume about 100MB of memory, and subsequent re-rereading of the file won't keep increasing memory usage.

Edit2: here's a minimal example using local atoms to try and see what's going on:

```
(defn parse-number [s] (if (= s "") nil (read-string s)))

(defn parse-line [line]
  (let [result (atom [])]
    (doseq [x (clojure.string/split line #",")]
      (swap! result conj (parse-number x)))
    @result))

(defn line-by-line-parser [file]
  (let [result (atom [])]
    (with-open [rdr (clojure.java.io/reader file)]
      (doseq [line (line-seq rdr)]
        (swap! result conj (parse-line line)))
      @result)))

;in the repl:
(def x (line-by-line-parser "C:\\temp\\history.csv")) ; memory goes up 1GB
(def x (line-by-line-parser "C:\\temp\\history.csv")) ; memory goes up an extra 1GB
; etc
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The 200MB sense because JAVA uses UCS-2 for text which take up two bytes for most char while in you csv. the chars will be typical 1 byte and only sometimes more than one.

Comment: "If I open and parse the file several times into the same variable, memory usage keep going up and I end up with a memory error and the program fails. " - can you share some code to demonstrate this? Possibly an MCVE.

Comment: Every field in a CSV file becomes a separate Clojure/Java string in memory after parsing.  Every Java string in JDK 8 requires 24 bytes for a String Object, plus 16 bytes for an array object, plus 2 bytes per char (they are stored in memory as UTF-16, 2 bytes per char, even if ASCII).  The 40 bytes per field might be far larger than 2 bytes per char, depending on how many fields your CSV file has.  If you use JDK 9 or later, compact strings enable a memory optimization of 1 byte per char in memory if a field contains only ASCII chars, but it does not reduce the 40 bytes per string/field.

Comment: @andy_fingerhut thank you for the explanation - is there a way to have Java/Clojure not box the data (they're all floats or nil)? also why is it increasing on every file read?

Comment: You could after reading each line convert the vector of strings into a double-array or float-array using a function you write yourself, although if you use a double-array, there is no way to store `nil` in such an array.  You could store `##NaN`, or some other special value your application recognizes as an unknown/missing value.  As for increasing on every file read, the JVM will not deallocate garbage until it needs the memory, typically, so either that is happening, or perhaps you are storing the return values in different vars, instead of the same one?

Comment: Oh, and if you prefer Clojure immutable vectors instead of mutable Java arrays, `(vector-of :float ...)` or `(vector-of :double ...)` store floats/doubles unboxed, so less memory than a "normal" Clojure vector, which stores everything boxed.  Again, no way to store `nil` in such a vector.

Comment: Another possibility on the memory increase:  It might be that the two `(def x ...)` in a row, the second one holds on to the previous data, until after the new data is completely parsed and create data structures in memory, so for at least an instant, both the old and the new are non-garbage in memory according to the JVM.  You could force the old to be reclaimable garbage by doing `(def x nil)` before the next file read.

Comment: Try to get rid of the `atom`s. I can imagine that using them you generate a lot of extra garbage objects. Your code is heavily imperative-like using the atoms. Instead, you should use `reduce` or `into` to parse each line in a more functional and idiomatic way.

Comment: @andy_fingerhut thank you all these comments helped!

Answer (score 2):

As long as you don't keep your parsed data under any GC roots (like `def` or `memoize` functions), the code you shown above should not leak.  You can easily prove that by looping your code for 100 times and see if you get an OOM (I don't expect any).  Having said that, there are things you can do to relieve memory pressure as suggested by others.

If you want to know exactly where the memory go, pick up a profiler like [this](https://github.com/clojure-goes-fast/clj-async-profiler) to deep dive into it.

My hunch on your case is just GC pressure (not leak).  Specifically on the use of `read-string`, much more than `conj`/`atom`.  Try replace `read-string` with something more low level (e.g. `Integer/parse`) and you should see a big difference.  `conj` on other the other hand, is super efficient from a persistent data-structure perspective (which Python don't use) but of course it will never beat primitive array (which Python use).  `atom` is usually used for concurrency. In your case, it can be replaced with `transient` (and `persistent!`) but I don't expect it will make a big difference.

**Update - add allocation flame graph**

- As you can see, `read-string` uses up 70% of memory allocation while running

[image]

Comment: This is a great answer - I didn't realise read-string was so heavy. Replacing with Float/parseFloat helped a lot! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, there are two things that bother me seeing how you use atoms:

1. The way you use them looks very imperative-like. Clojure is a funcitonal programming language and the way you use them is not very idiomatic.
2. My guess is that each `swap` call generates a bunch of garbage objects which could explain the memory usage.

Number one and number two can be solved using `into` or `reduce`. As a benefit, the resulting code will be shorter.

I am more familiar with `reduce`, so here is an example using it:

```
(defn parse-number [s] (if (= s "") nil (read-string s)))

(defn parse-line [line]
  (reduce #(conj %1 (parse-number %2))
          []
          (clojure.string/split line #",")))

(defn line-by-line-parser [file]
  (with-open [rdr (clojure.java.io/reader file)]
    (reduce #(conj %1 (parse-line %2))
            []
            (line-seq rdr))))
```

As I do not have your test data I can only guess that it could solve your problem. So, I would be happy if you tested it and report if there are any improvements.

Comment: Thank you Joshua. My first solutions were all "clojuresque" and I resorted to atoms to make sure things would be dealt with sequentially and garbage collected. Your solution while very clean didn't help re memory. What seems to help me so far is to unbox data to float as much as possible.

Comment: @alex314159 what a shame. Have you tried a dedicated csv parsing library like https://github.com/clojure/data.csv ?

Comment: yes that was my first solution. I've now managed to have my 50MB file "just" use 500MB memory and not grow on reload, which is not great but acceptable. Makes you appreciate the good work behind Python pandas!